# How to correctly authenticate Python Flask-WTF web app users against Python Flask API using JWT

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm new to Python, but have previous experience writing .Net web apps.

I'm working on a website written in Python using Flask-WTF (html pages with forms and individual routes for GET and POST requests). The app makes calls against a Python Flask API that talks to a MySQL db for user authentication (user table with names and hashed passwords). Everything the user sees is handled by the web app UI, and all the logic is handled by the API.

I followed Miguel's Mega-Tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) to learn the basics of the Python language and how to solve a number of problems along the way.

I need my users to log in once a day (set tokens to expire every 12-24 hours or so), but then have access to the app to perform whatever actions they need. I have a Login form that grabs username/password and submits that to an API endpoint. The API verifies the user data against the db, generates JWTs (access and refresh tokens), and writes them to cookies in the response. I am able to see that the cookies are set in the web app after the initial login and verified the contents using https://jwt.io. The only thing I need from the user login after verification is the username for when a user makes a change to database entries.

The Problem: How do I actually use the info in the cookies to call subsequent @jwt_protected methods in the API? When I add the @jwt_required to a post(self) function and try to access it I'm getting back a 401 with  { "msg": "Missing cookie "access_token_cookie"" } that appears to be coming from the jwt_flask_extended library. I used "access_token_cookie" as the name of the cookie for the JWT token. Are the tokens magically handled by FlaskWTF/flask_jwt_extended and I'm just using it wrong? Do I need take the info out of the cookie and add it as a header on subsequent requests? If I send the info in a header, how does the API know where to look? I have a feeling it's something minor where I'm just not connecting the obvious dots.

I'll create a standalone app to test out just the authentication features between UIs and APIs that can be shared as opposed to trying to rip out existing code minimize the existing app and api to the bare minimums in case anybody else comes across a similar problem. This might also show me what my problem really is.

The final version of the app and api will both be hosted in a Cloudfoundry environment in case that has any bearing on suggestions.

Comment: Have you read up on this? https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tokens_in_cookies. You should use `set_access_cookies` and `set_refresh_cookies` to make sure the cookies are set with the correct name as they are looked for in an incoming request, which can be configured via various app.config options.

Comment: @vimalloc - Thanks for the reply. I have re-read your documentation and I'm pretty sure I'm using the code the same as in the link (after verifying user, I create the tokens and add the JWT in the cookie response). I even copied your code exactly. In the UI after the call completes for login, I can see the cookies are set appropriately using `req.cookies.get('access_token_cookie')`. I then attempt to call a @jwt_protected function, but immediately get back 401 with the missing cookie message. I'm thinking maybe I have a package conflict somewhere

Comment: If I remove the `@jwt_protected` and immediately `print(get_jwt_identity()` it shows as "None"

Comment: I created a new web app and API just to for test. When using Postman calling the API to retrieve the tokens and immediately making additional calls to `@jwt_protected` functions worked. In the web app, I made the same API call, retrieved the tokens, then immediately called the same `@jwt_protected` protected function, but it failed. To get the app to work, I need to make the first request, grab the cookies with `allcookies = req.cookies` then for all future requests specify the cookies with `req = requests.get(url=URL,cookies=allcookies)`. Not optimal and there's a CSRF issue, but progress.